# New low-quality post tool: what to do for "This was just a stab in the dark?"

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, review

After using the [Low Quality Posts review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/) for a little while, I've noticed a trend that when someone doesn't know the answer they take a wild stab and post it as the answer. What action should I take in the tool for this behavior? I'm choosing *Not Sure* for now, since obviously I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: Links to examples?

Comment: My first instinct as an answer was http://loyalkng.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/flamethrower.jpg but seeing a couple of examples would indeed be helpful!

Comment: I'll start posting any I come across when I use the tool.

Comment: Well, look what I found: A Jon Skeet possible low quality :( http://stackoverflow.com/review-beta/low-quality-posts/558009

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said, it would be cool to see some examples but in general, an answer being a "Stab in the dark"  alone shouldn't warrant any review action. The way to deal with incorrect answers is downvoting, not deleting.

After all, "stab in the dark" is a subjective category, and we don't *know* for certain how the answer came about. Maybe it was just worded by a very knowledgeable user with poor writing abilities.

So if you want to vote to delete, look whether the answer has other, legitimate problems - for example, whether it consists of a link only, or should be a comment.

If those criteria don't apply, downvote if you feel it's a blatantly incorrect answer; otherwise, move on.

Answer (score 1):

If the "stab in the dark" explains how to try the suggested solution, it is an answer.

If it only asks "have you tried [this]" or "Try [this]", where [this] is a topic, not a solution, it is a comment.

There are grey areas though, of course, especially depending upon how the question asks for solutions.